# Ruby on Rails JSON.parse(object.to_json) doesn't return the original object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

It seems that with an object like this:

```
#<Course id: 1, name: "Targeting Triple Negative Breast Cancer", description: nil, disclosure: nil, created_at: "2010-11-11 14:43:31", updated_at: "2010-11-11 14:43:31", picture: nil, course_reference_id: nil, authors: "Lisa A. Carey, M.D.", volumn_number: nil, publication_date: nil, expiration_date: nil, credits: 1, featured: false>
```

I should be able to do `JSON.parse(course.to_json)`, but when I try this, instead of returning the original object, I get the equivalent of Course.new (an object with nil attributes).

When I do `course.to_json` I get:

```
"{\"attributes\":{\"name\":\"Targeting Triple Negative Breast Cancer\",\"expiration_date\":null,\"created_at\":\"2010-11-11 14:43:31\",\"featured\":\"0\",\"publication_date\":null,\"updated_at\":\"2010-11-11 14:43:31\",\"id\":\"1\",\"disclosure\":null,\"volumn_number\":null,\"credits\":\"1\",\"authors\":\"Lisa A. Carey, M.D.\",\"course_reference_id\":null,\"description\":null,\"picture\":null},\"json_class\":\"Course\",\"attributes_cache\":{}}"
```

But when I do `JSON.parse(course.to_json)` I get:

```
#<Course id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, disclosure: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, picture: nil, course_reference_id: nil, authors: nil, volumn_number: nil, publication_date: nil, expiration_date: nil, credits: nil, featured: false>
```

I am using Rails 2.3.5 and I get the same result with other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serialize/deserialize the object use `#to_json` and `#from_json`. Don't try to parse the JSON string directly.

```
json = Course.new(...).to_json
Course.new.from_json(json)
```

Also note you should avoid calling `JSON.parse` directly. Use `ActiveSupport::JSON` bridge instead.

Comment: When I try that I get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: json_class`